# Inserting coordinates from Google Maps into a Database

Tags: postgis, google-maps, coordinates

I am using Android Google Maps to take the coordinates off a location on the map and I want to insert it into a PostgreSQL database.

I know I have to use PostGIS but how can I do that?

Who can point me in the right direction?

My insertion query in Java looks like:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO modul (denumire, adresa, tip_retea, geom, poza)";
query += " VALUES ('" 
     + getset.getDenumire() + "', '" 
     + getset.getAdresa() + "', '"
     + getset.getTipretea()+ "', 
     ST_PointFromText('point(" + point.getX() + " " + point.getY()+ ")', 1), '" 
     + getset.getImagine() + "');";
```

Which generates me the following query:

```
INSERT INTO modul (denumire, adresa, tip_retea, geom, poza) VALUES ('', '', '', ST_PointFromText('point(23.78977 44.320948)', 1), 'irrelevant b64 encoded image');
```

But how can I properly insert the coordinates into a database?

What datatype does the column 'geom' need to be?

Comment: It needs to be a geometry datatype, though you can be more specific and declare a particular type, such as point, linestring, polygon, and a spatial reference id, eg, `geom geometry (POLYGON, 4326)` or just `geom geometry`;

Comment: I don't have the geometry datatype, even though I have PostGIS installed.

Comment: Then you don't have Postgis installed properly. Providing a geometry datatype to Postgres is one of the key things Postgis does :D You may need to explicity add it to the database you are working on. Do you see geometry_columns view and spatial_ref_sys table in the specific database you are working on.

Comment: I will try reinstalling, I'll come back with an answer shortly.

Comment: It is working now, I have successfully inserted the coordinates into the database. Thank you.

Comment: Good. Enjoy Postgis, it is fabulous :D